# C# 6.0. Elvis-оператор для переменных типа dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

Добрый день!

При написании приложения на MVC возникла следующая ситуация: У меня есть в базе данных таблица `User`, в которой есть поле `IdRole`, которое может быть `null`. Класс-модель для таблицы `User` выглядит так (эта модель сгенерировалась с помощью ADO.NET):

```
[Table("risksdb.user")]
public partial class user
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public user()
    {
        risk_record = new HashSet<risk_record>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int IdUser { get; set; }

    public int? IdRole { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(45)]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(45)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<risk_record> risk_record { get; set; }

    public virtual role role { get; set; }
}
```

Как видно, свойство `Role` может принимать `null`. Для вывода таблицы `user`, я использую `ViewBag`, который является `dynamic`. В него (`ViewBag.Users`)я помещаю `IEnumerable<user> Users` в своем контроллере и в cshtml-файле я вывожу его примерно так:

```html
<tr>
    <td><p>IdUser</p></td>
    <td><p>IdRole</p></td>
    <td><p>Login</p></td>
    <td><p>Password</p></td>
</tr>
@foreach (var u in ViewBag.Users)
{
    <tr>
        <td><p>@u.IdUser</p></td>
        <td><p>@u.IdRole</p></td>
        <td><p>@u.Login</p></td>
        <td><p>@u.Password</p></td>
    </tr>
}
```

**Вопрос**: Нужно ли делать проверку на null для поля переменной типа `dynamic` или нет? Если да, то как правильно сделать это и где (в контроллере или еще где-то)?

**Доп. вопрос**: Как лучше передавать в cshtml-файл модель: через `ViewBag` или через параметр `object model`?

Comment: передавать лучше объект viewmodel, содержащий данные модели и доп. данные (пр. список Users) которые необходимы для построения представления

Comment: @Ruslan_K получается, необходимо создать для каждой страницы свои классы ViewModel? и в каждый View будет передаваться своя ViewModel, так?

Comment: @Ruslan_K и еще, вы написали: _"объект viewmodel, содержащий данные модели"_. Про какую модель Вы говорите? сам класс `user` или что-то другое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Зависит от того, может быть у этой переменной значение `null` или нет. Если в контроллере всегда безусловно что-то присваиваете `ViewBag.Users`, то и над проверкой заморачиваться ни к чему.
Проверку нужно проводить там, где может возникнуть ошибка. Например, в представлении ошибка может возникнуть в цикле `foreach`, если `ViewBag.Users` будет равен `null`.

2) Конечно же через object model. Это удобный и общепринятый механизм. Достаточно в представлении (cshtml-файл) добавить строку `@model IEnumerable<user>` и далее к модели обращаться через переменную `Model`.
Это сразу даёт понимание типа модели. С передачей через ViewBag нет строгой типизации и понять, какого типа там данные может быть сложно.
P.s. Просто представьте, что вы программируете только бизнес-логику приложения, а все представления в вашей команде пишет "верстальщик". Чтобы он каждый раз не спрашивал вас как получить из модели те или иные данные вы можете сказать ему, что в качестве модели передаете экземпляр класса User, поля данных которого заведомо описаны в вашем коде.

Comment: В этом и вопрос: к примеру, если приложение не подключится к базе данных, то тогда переменная `ViewBag.Users` будет `null` и в цикле вылетит исключение. Как я понял, проверку нужно сделать в контроллере, верно (`users` запрашиваются из базы данных в контроллере)? Также я хотел бы узнать: можно ли с помощью данного оператора проверять на null переменные типа `dynamic`? Я вроде как попробовал, но компилятор ругался.

Comment: Если приложение не подключится к БД, то исключение возникнет уже на этапе того самого подключения) До проверки на null просто не дойдете) А вообще в чем смысл проверять в контроллере? Пустой результат - тоже результат. Во вьюхе, если модель равна null, то можно вывести сообщение, что данных нет. А что делать в контроллере? Это нормальная практика передавать в представление null. По поводу dynamic и null вы правы, обычно сравнение не пройдет. Делайте так: if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, ViewBag.Users)) {
  .......
}